# Background data loading and resolver in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a component with multiple tabs: `tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3`. Navigating between tabs happens by the route. `tab1` is the default tab that is active when the user visits the page. `tab3` required an API call to get data to show. I want to load this data in the background in the resolver of the `WrapperComponent` (wrapper above these tabs) to prevent long loading of the `tab3`. Also I have resolver for `tab3` for cases when user load page by url that contains `tab3`. When the user navigates `tab3` I want to wait for data loading and do not call it again.
So I have service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataStorageService {
fetchData(requestId: string): void {
    this.data= this.reportsApi.getData(requestId).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  getData(): Observable<data[]> {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

So in the resolver of `WrapperComponent` I am calling `DataStorageService.fetchData` to start loading data in background.

And in the resolver of the `tab3` I just return `this.data` from service:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.DataStorageService.getData();
  }
```

It work fine besides initial data loading. So when I load the page on `tab1` data is not started loading. I fixed it with additional line in `fetchData`:

```
 fetchData(requestId: string): void {
        this.data= this.reportsApi.getData(requestId).pipe(shareReplay(1));
        this.data.subscribe(v => v);
      }
```

But it doesn't seem correct. I also tried to use `BehaviorSubject`, `ReplaySubject` in such way:

```
fetchData(requestId: string): void {
  this.reportsApi.getData(requestId).subscribe(data => this.data = data)
}
```

And pass it `asObservable` to resolver, but it was not a success too. How I can implement this?

Answer (score -1):

You need call `fetchData` somewhere, for example in `getData`.

Comment: It will rewrite `this.data` and i will get new observable and new api request

Comment: So u can call it in constructor.

Comment: In what constructor? If in the constructor of the `WrapperComponent` - it will not change anything. If in the constructor of `tab3` component - it is not what i want at all

Comment: I have not noticed that u call `fetchData` i wrapper resolver :P But u can call it in constructor of `DataStorageService`. Angular creates services when it's first time needed.

Comment: It will not fix my problem. As i wrote. `this.data` is hot observable, but it will not be called until someone subscribes to it. So this i `fixed` with empty subscribe. Also i dont wabt this data to be in router snapshot for all tabs, except `tab3`

Comment: resolver should subscribe returned data, but observable must be completed so you can add `pipe(take(1))` in `resolve` function

Comment: Did you see my comment above? Http request is not triggered until there will be at least one subscribe. And i want to start loading data at tab1 or tab2